# Whats the cleanest workaround to get paver 1.0.3 working on Windows XP without the paths.py _isdir bug?

Tags: python, windows-xp, paver

Until now I have been developing on a Windows 7 system. Recently i had to reset my entire dev enviromemt on a Windows XP system.
My paver builds stopped working, i traced the reason for the failure to this bug. filled on paths.py [ https://github.com/dottedmag/path.py/issues/16 ].

Since paver is using a custom edited version of this file, the solution does not seem to be a simple 'update the paths.py module'. It also looks like there isnt a build of paver with the patch merged in.

Has someone else encountered this  problem, whats the workaround that you came up with?

Answer (score 0):

looks lke the only way out is to patch the Paver's path.py with this patch:

https://github.com/dottedmag/path.py/commit/bc34208483a0eeadd94a1275475b293ec77a6114